# Changing the starting point for an existing model without reconstructing it

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I've looked through JuMP's documentation, but did not find it there:

How can I modify just a starting point for variables of an existing model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
setvalue(x[i],1.0)
```

to give a starting point for the variable `x[i]` which will be passed to the solver on the next `solve()` call. This can be done at any time.